# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/file.jpg: open failed: EEXIST (File exists) in kotlin

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, exists

I am making a function to download a file from a server. The function to download the file works fine. However, when the user enters the file explorer and manually deletes the file and tries to download again, the error java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/File.jpg: open failed: EEXIST (File exists) occurs. Is there a way to solve this without using the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

File download is in progress with HTTPUriConnection, and it reads as inputstream and saves the file in the path designated as outputstream.

The download path I specified is "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS".

Comment: Hard-coded file paths are disabled since Android 11. Try Scoped Storage.

Comment: If the user does not delete that file can you download it a second time and overwrite the first one? Your app should be able to do so.  Which Android version on used device?

Comment: Use a different name when you encounter the error, such as `File (2).jpg`. Or, use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and allow the user to choose where yo should save the content.

Comment: In my case, using Android 11 and If the user does not delete the file, the first file can be overwritten.